# pg_hba.conf - psql local login without password

Tags: postgresql, user-management

I have these settings in my `pg_hba.conf` for a PostgreSQL-12.6 installation

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
local   all             postgres                                trust   # ident
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust   # md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

I execpt `local    all    postgres    trust` shoudl allow me to log in locally to `psql` **without** being queuried for a password as the `postgres` unix user.

However:

```
postgres@my-vm:/opt/db/postgres/bin> psql
Password for user postgres:
```

there is no existing psql password for the `postgres` user yet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
local  all  all       md5  
local  all  postgres  trust   # ident
```

Remember that the entries in pg_hba are processed *in the order they given*.

> "local  all  postgres  trust" ... should allow me to log in ... without ... password

And it *would*, if it appeared *before* the line that forced *every* local connection to use **md5** authentication!